# Transform ordering of photos in iPhoto to files

Tags: photos.app

I use iPhoto to organize my photos, especially to order them. If I copy a whole album, for example the last holiday trip, to an usb stick, all images are transfered, but not in the order I created in iPhoto (obviously ^^). Is there a way to automatically rename the files so they match the ordering I created in iPhoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

1. Select all photos in your manually sorted album (e.g. using <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Choose `File`–`Export...` from the menu (or hit <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>)
3. Select "Sequential" for File name, and enter a base name (which will be followed by numbers) [image: List item]
4. In the next dialog, choose the target folder (e.g. directly on your USB drive). Your photos will be exported there, and sorting them by file name will result in your beloved custom sort order from iPhoto!

In step 3, you might also want to select other options such as picture size and file format – this comes in handy if you don't need the full-resolution versions to be exported.